# Matrix $M$ such that $M^3 = -M$

Tags: linear-algebra

I couldn't find a similar question.
I want to prove that a matrix $M$ such that $M^3 = -M$ satisfies

$R^3 = ker(M)\oplus ker(M^2+I)$

And that the dimension of $Ker(M^2+I)$ is even.

I know how to prove that $Ker(M)\cap Ker(M^2+I) = {0}$, but then, I don't know how to proceed (to show that $R^3$ is written by elements of the two kernels and its dimension). Any help is welcomed. Thank you

Comment: If your matrix $M$ known to be $3\times 3$? You need to say that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, the exercise said that, but Pedro was able to solve it in an arbitrary dimension :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $M^3+M = M(M^2+1)$, so $p(X) = X(X^2+1)$ annihilates $M$. Since $X$ and $X^2+1$ are coprime, and in fact $g(X)X+f(X)(X^2+1) = 1$ for $g(X) = -X$ and $f(X) = 1$, any vector can be written as a sum of two vectors $v_1+v_2$ where $v_1 = g(M)Mv$ and $v_2 = g(M)(M^2+1)v$, and certainly $v_1\in \ker(M^2+1)$ while $v_2\in \ker M$.

Moreover, this shows that if $v$ is in both kernels it is zero, for in such case $v_1=v_2=0$. Observe that this proof works whenever a polynomial $p$ annihilates a matrix and you have a decomposition of $p$ into irreducible factors.

To show that the kernel $V$ of $M^2+1$ is of even real dimension, note that such vectors satisfy $M^2v=-v$, so the operator $M : V\to V$ can be used to extend the $\mathbb R$-structure to a $\mathbb C$-structure by declaring that $iv = Mv$ for $v\in V$, and complex vector spaces have even real dimension.

Comment: Thank you Pedro, your solution is very clear